# Changing specific index of an array in state instead of all of my state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a React refresher. I set state in App.js and created an event called handleUserNameChange() to change usernames in the state object. Each input from UserInput.js should change it's relative UserOutput component's username in state that's set in App.js. How can I make so that when I type text into one input it only changes one index in my users array in state? Do I need to change my handleUserNameChange event?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

//Components
import UserInput from './UserInput/UserInput';
import UserOutput from './UserOutput/UserOutput';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    users: [
      {user: 'Debbie'},
      {user: 'Ronald'}
    ]
  };

  handleUserNameChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      users: [
        {user: event.target.value},
        {user: event.target.value}
      ]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <UserOutput
          username = {this.state.users[0].user}
        />

        <UserInput
          nameChange={this.handleUserNameChange} />

        <UserOutput 
          username={this.state.users[1].user}

        />
        <UserInput
          nameChange={this.handleUserNameChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

UserOuput.js

```
import React from 'react';

const UserOutput =(props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{props.username}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserOutput;
```

UserInput.js

```
import React from 'react';

const UserInput = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text"
        onChange={props.nameChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserInput;
```

Answer (score 1):

In App.js:

```
<UserInput
  nameChange={this.handleUserNameChange(0)}//0 for first, 1 for second  
/>

handleUserNameChange = (index) => (event) => {
  this.setState({
    users: this.state.users.map(
      (user,i)=>
        (i===index)
          ? event.target.value
          : user
    )
  });
};
```

It would probably be better to not hardcode user 0 and user 1 but just map the state to react modules.

```
render() {
  const userInput = index =>
    <UserInput
      nameChange={this.handleUserNameChange(index)} />;
  const UserOutput = user =>
    <UserOutput
      username = {user}/>;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      this.state.users.map(
        (user,index)=>
          <div>{userInput(index)}{UserOutput(user)}</div>
      )
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

pass the index value in `handleUserNameChange` function from render function and use double arrow in `handleUserNameChange` to get the index value.

```
handleUserNameChange = index => event => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
       const users = [...prevState.users];
       users[index].user = event.target.value;
       return { users };
    });
};

render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    {this.state.users.map((user, index) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <UserOutput username={user} />
        <UserInput nameChange={this.handleUserNameChange(index)} />
      </React.Fragment>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

}